# FileOpenPicker not giving file path

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get a fileopenpicker to give me the filepath of a selected file, however, when the fileopenpicker resumes, it does not give me the file path, the ContinueFileOpenPicker method is not used, I placed a breakpoint on it, and it did not trigger. Any ideas as to why this is?
I'm using using Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

```
private async void btnPickFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        openPicker.ContinuationData["filePath"] = "GetFilePath";
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = App.Current as App;
        if (app.FilePickerContinuationArgs != null)
        {
            this.ContinueFileOpenPicker(app.FilePickerContinuationArgs);
        }
    }

    public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((args.ContinuationData["filePath"] as string) == "GetfilePath" &&
            args.Files != null &&
            args.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            StorageFile file = args.Files[0];
            string filePath = file.Path;
            FilePath.Text = file.Path;
        }         
    }
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is only of breakpoint do not hit, then make sure you're running the app in Debug mode. if you'll run your app in Release mode, then no breakpoint will hit. Still if you're facing issue, then read further.

You can follow the steps from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642086(v=vs.105).aspx).

Your code looks okay but you might be missing something somewhere. here I'm briefing the procedure with code snippet.

**First Step:**
write code to open file picker in the specific page in any event handler.

```
    // MainPage.xaml.cs file

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        openPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
        openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "pickFile";
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
    }
```

Then there are few things to be added in your project's `App.xaml.cs` file

**Second Step:**  Declare a global variable in `App.xaml.cs` file for `FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs`.

```
    public FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs FilePickerContinuationArgs { get; set; }
```

**Third Step:**
When your app resumes after picking up a file, it will call `ContractActivated` event, so need to handle that event in `InitializePhoneApplication` method in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
    // Handle contract activation such as a file open or save picker
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.ContractActivated += Application_ContractActivated;
```

Now define the event handler `Application_ContractActivated` in `App.xaml.cs` file as per below.

```
    // App.xaml.cs file

    // Code to execute when a contract activation such as a file open or save picker returns 
    // with the picked file or other return values
    private void Application_ContractActivated(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var filePickerContinuationArgs = e as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
        if (filePickerContinuationArgs != null)
        {
            this.FilePickerContinuationArgs = filePickerContinuationArgs;
        }
    }
```

**Fourth Step:**
Now come back to the page where you want to call `FileOpenPicker` and override the `OnNavigatedTo()` method as per below.

```
    // MainPage.xaml.cs file

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = App.Current as App;
        if (app.FilePickerContinuationArgs != null)
        {
            this.ContinueFileOpenPicker(app.FilePickerContinuationArgs);
        }
    }
```

Then define the `ContinueFileOpenPicker` event handler as per below.

```
    // MainPage.xaml.cs file

    public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        if ((args.ContinuationData["Operation"] as string) == "pickFile" &&
            args.Files != null &&
            args.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            StorageFile file = args.Files[0];
            string filePath = file.Path;
            MessageBox.Show(filePath);
        }
    }
```

You're done..!!
This code is working if you do everything right.

Hope it helps..
Cheers..

Comment: This worked! I am unsure why my original code didn't work, the only change needed was in the ContinueFileOpenPicker. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I recognized your actual mistake here.

Check the screenshot.

[image]

I hope you also recognized your issue.

One mistake of Capital-Small letter can make a developer go mad..! :-)

Comment: I never noticed that! Weird that it was never flagged up. Thanks again for your earlier help :)